# How to I get the UDP remote endpoint when using boost asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Let's say I've recoderded an handler for asynchronous receive on an UDP socket (which joined a **multicast group**):

```
         udpSocket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer)),
                                 boost::bind(&receiveCallback,
                                              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Here the idea is that I want to get the **remote** address and port in the receiveCallBack when receiving an UDP pacquet. How to do that? Is there a specific placeholder? If not, once in a Callback how to get that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to use the `receive_from` call, which takes in a `boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint` to capture sender data.

There is an example multicast receiver in the boost asio examples [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/receiver.cpp).  Specifically this block:

```
socket_.async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
    boost::bind(&receiver::handle_receive_from, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Comment: Thnx. I've found that one meanwhile: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime7/src.html . Approved! :-)